# Adding Odia Font in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.6, font, internationalization

I am preparing GIS maps for the local community of Odisha, India. As per their requirement, the local language needs to be displayed on the map.

How can I add the Odiya language font in ArcMap?

Comment: Arcgis use system font so you just need to install it on your system and it will be available to arcgis (you may need to restart arcgis and/or your computer). For witch font you need to install that another question that is not gis related and outside of the scope of this site...

Comment: https://oriya.indiatyping.com/index.php/download-oriya-font